# xamarin forms cannot implicitly convert type 'system.threading.tasks.task<System.collections.generic list to system.collections.generic List

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Hi I am new to programming, but currently I encounter xamarin forms **cannot implicitly convert type 'system.threading.tasks.task> to system.collections.generic.List**
as I am trying to use global variable upon launching the app to optimized the app
when I am trying to set the List of menu items into the global variable which will be access by the other pages, it gave me that error. I have no idea how to solve that issue so someone please help me

Here is my 
App.cs

```
private static int globalVariable = 1;
        public static List<MenuItemModel> foodList = new List<MenuItemModel>();
        private static List<MenuItemModel> beverageList = new List<MenuItemModel>();
        public static int GlobalVariable
        {
            get { return globalVariable; }
            set { globalVariable = value; }
        }
        public static List<MenuItemModel> FoodList
        {
            get { return foodList; }
            set { foodList = value; }
        }
        public static List<MenuItemModel> BeverageList
        {
            get { return beverageList; }
            set { beverageList = value; }
        }

        public App()
        {
            GlobalVariable = 10;

            BeverageList = getBeverageList();
            FoodList = getFoodList();
        }
public async Task<List<MenuItemModel>> getBeverageList()
        {
            ConstantCS constant = new ConstantCS();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://172.20.129.44/");


            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = client.GetAsync("WebServices/menu.svc/GetBeveragesJSON").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

                int itemId_;
                string itemName_;
                string itemCategory_;
                string itemSubCategory_;
                string itemDescription_;
                string itemImage_;
                int itemQuantity_;
                double itemPrice_;
                string itemStatus_;
                string itemAddOn_;

                for (int i = 0; i < dynamicObject.d.Count; i++)
                {
                    itemId_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemID"];
                    itemName_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemName"].ToString();
                    itemCategory_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemCategory"].ToString();
                    itemSubCategory_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemSubCategory"].ToString();
                    itemDescription_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemDesc"].ToString();
                    itemImage_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemImg"].ToString();
                    itemQuantity_ = int.Parse(dynamicObject.d[i]["itemQty"].ToString());
                    itemPrice_ = double.Parse(dynamicObject.d[i]["itemPrice"].ToString());
                    itemStatus_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemStatus"].ToString();
                    itemAddOn_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemRequest"].ToString();

                    string itemURL_ = constant.PhotoBaseURL + itemImage_;



                    beverageList.Add(new MenuItemModel(itemId_, itemName_, itemCategory_, itemSubCategory_, itemDescription_, itemURL_, itemQuantity_, itemPrice_, itemStatus_, itemAddOn_));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine("It entered else not if");
            }
            return beverageList;
        }
```

[image: The error that was shown]
Thanks!

Comment: First off - you shouldn't be doing heavy lifting in a constructor. Secondly - you're calling an async method, but not awaiting it. Thus, you're getting a task back. So, you'll need to write `await getBeverageList()` and mark the method as async. However, constructors cannot be async, so I'd recommend moving all the heavy lifting into a method named something like `async void Init()`.

Comment: @Rob I tried putting the await in front of getBeverageList() but they will state that this method is not a asyn method. Moreover, I wasn't able to change the App() to async. And what do you mean by async void Init()? any example?

Comment: Yes - because `App()` is a constructor. You'll need to create a new method named whatever you like, in my example it's named `Init`. Mark *that* method as `Init()`, and put the `getBeverageList()`, `getFoodList()` inside the `Init` function. Then of course, you'd need to call `obj.Init()` after creating a new `App`

Comment: @Rob sorry still couldn't understand what you are saying... do you mind writing out in codes as an example? thank you!

Comment: @Rob sorry still couldn't understand what you are saying... do you mind writing out in codes as an example? thank you! 

public App()
{
InitBeverageAndFoodList();
}
public async void InitBeverageAndFoodList()
        {
            BeverageList = await getBeverageList();
            FoodList = await getFoodList();
        }

And it worked! Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything `async` in `getBeverageList()`, so you can safely change its signature to

```cs
public List<MenuItemModel> getBeverageList()
```

After that, you should stop for a few days, and learn about async/await and TPL...