# Xamarin.Forms Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.threading.tasks.task> to system.collections.generic.List

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I am new to programming, but currently I encounter xamarin forms cannot implicitly convert type 'system.threading.tasks.task> to system.collections.generic.List as I am trying to use global variable upon launching the app to optimized the app when I am trying to set the List of menu items into the global variable which will be access by the other pages, it gave me that error. I have no idea how to solve that issue so someone please help me

Here is my App.cs

```
private static int globalVariable = 1;
public static List<MenuItemModel> foodList = new List<MenuItemModel>();
private static List<MenuItemModel> beverageList = new List<MenuItemModel>();
public static int GlobalVariable
{
    get { return globalVariable; }
    set { globalVariable = value; }
}
public static List<MenuItemModel> FoodList
{
    get { return foodList; }
    set { foodList = value; }
}
public static List<MenuItemModel> BeverageList
{
    get { return beverageList; }
    set { beverageList = value; }
}

public App()
{
    GlobalVariable = 10;

    BeverageList = getBeverageList();
    FoodList = getFoodList();
}
public async Task<List<MenuItemModel>> getBeverageList()
{
    ConstantCS constant = new ConstantCS();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://172.20.129.44/");


    // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response = client.GetAsync("WebServices/menu.svc/GetBeveragesJSON").Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

        int itemId_;
        string itemName_;
        string itemCategory_;
        string itemSubCategory_;
        string itemDescription_;
        string itemImage_;
        int itemQuantity_;
        double itemPrice_;
        string itemStatus_;
        string itemAddOn_;

        for (int i = 0; i < dynamicObject.d.Count; i++)
        {
            itemId_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemID"];
            itemName_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemName"].ToString();
            itemCategory_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemCategory"].ToString();
            itemSubCategory_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemSubCategory"].ToString();
            itemDescription_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemDesc"].ToString();
            itemImage_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemImg"].ToString();
            itemQuantity_ = int.Parse(dynamicObject.d[i]["itemQty"].ToString());
            itemPrice_ = double.Parse(dynamicObject.d[i]["itemPrice"].ToString());
            itemStatus_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemStatus"].ToString();
            itemAddOn_ = dynamicObject.d[i]["itemRequest"].ToString();

            string itemURL_ = constant.PhotoBaseURL + itemImage_;



            beverageList.Add(new MenuItemModel(itemId_, itemName_, itemCategory_, itemSubCategory_, itemDescription_, itemURL_, itemQuantity_, itemPrice_, itemStatus_, itemAddOn_));
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine("It entered else not if");
    }
    return beverageList;
}
```

The error that was shown

Comment: Thankuu Felix it really help me

Comment: please accept my answer if it helped you :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xamarin forms cannot implicitly convert type 'system.threading.tasks.task<System.collections.generic list to system.collections.generic List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623973/xamarin-forms-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-threading-tasks-tasksystem)

Comment: do not ask the same question twice under 2 different accounts. Thanks. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623973/xamarin-forms-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-threading-tasks-tasksystem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warp an extra async Method into your constructor:

```
public App()
{
    Initialize(); //no need to await this
}

public async Task Initialize()
{
    GlobalVariable = 10;

    BeverageList = await getBeverageList(); //use await here!
    FoodList = await getFoodList();         //use await here!
}
```

now you can `await` the results of `getFoodList()` and `getBeverageList()`.

Otherwise the `Task` itself is returned. Which leads to your error:

> **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List< MenuItemModel >**.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? There's no such thing as an async constructor.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix you are right. Did not thought about this. I fixed it.